# undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x8f53b44>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I know others asked this question, but the answers didn't solve my problem.

I'm getting this error when trying the sign up feature: `"undefined local variable or method 'confirmed_at' for #<User:0x8f53b44>"`

My migration looks like this:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Customization
      t.string :name
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
  end
end
```

And I added `devise :confirmable` to the User model.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: and you ran the migration, and reloaded your models?   What does your schema.rb look like ?

Comment: Same question as @Doon, did you run `rake db:migrate` after adding the confirmable module.  Also, make sure you uncomment the index declaration on the confirmation token:  `add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true`

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate before adding the confirmable module, so I dropped and ran it again, but now I'm getting this error: "550 Cannot receive from specified address". I believe I should change the email address?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and @tagCincy's answer solved my problem.
All you need is to uncomment index line in migrations

> `add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true`